# Cast std::string (guaranteed numeric) to an unsigned char

Tags: c++, casting, stringstream, unsigned-char

I've created a template for casting strings do different data types, and it's having issues when the data type is an unsigned char.

```
template<class TYPE>
bool TryParse(const std::string value, TYPE &out)
{
    std::istringstream iss(value);
    iss >> out;

    if (iss.fail())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is the `istringstream` will treat the first character it sees as a char, instead of treating it as a numeric string.  So if I pass a value of "255", the value returned will be '2'.

Would the best solution be casting the `out` variable as an unsigned int, perform the operation, then cast back again?

Comment: you could use `boost::lexical_cast` -- it doesn't address your specific question, but it does keep you from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Also, consider passing `value` by reference.  As it is, you are forcing the caller to copy strings for no good reason.

Comment: Why don't you just add a specialization for `char`?

Comment: @Deduplicator You mean overload, right? (Specializing functions is highly discouraged.)

Comment: @cdhowie: Is it? I know it's fairly new, but I don't know about discouraged...

Comment: @Deduplicator See *[Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)* for an excellent write-up about the pitfalls of specializing functions. It was written in 2001, so this isn't exactly new at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having an overload that applies specifically to `unsigned char` cases since you need to use an intermediate type.

```
bool TryParse(const std::string & value, unsigned char & out)
{
    std::istringstream iss(value);
    unsigned int i;
    iss >> i;

    if (iss.fail()) { return false; }

    // The less-than-min check is technically redundant because both i and out
    // are unsigned, but it makes me feel better having it there.  It will become
    // necessary for the "signed char" overload, anyway.
    if (i > std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() ||
        i < std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min()) {
            throw std::overflow_error();
            // Or you could "return false" instead, if that makes more sense.
    }

    out = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);
    return true;
}
```

You can use a nearly identical function for `signed char`.  (Just replace every `unsigned` with `signed`.)

I would not suggest using an intermediate type in your template, because you would need to use the widest possible type, and there isn't any one type that would work.  `unsigned long long int` wouldn't be compatible with `signed long long int`, for example, and vice-versa -- and neither of those types would be compatible with `float` or `double`.  Having a base template that uses the requested type directly, with overloads for problematic types (`char`, for example) is the right approach.

---

Note that I have changed the `value` parameter to be a reference to const string, as this means that the caller is not required to copy the string for no reason.  I would suggest changing your template function as well.